How to set complicated git config with quotes over ssh?
% ssh me@my-vm "git config --global alias.l 'log --graph --all --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset"'" 
zsh: no matches found: git config --global alias.l 'log --graph --all --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset 
I have no idea why this zsh error is happening.
Take on the other hand a simpler git config
% ssh me@my-vm "git config --global user.name 'First Last'"
Warning: Permanently added 'my-vm' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
which works flawlessly. Which leads me to believe that the issue isn't me trying to set git config but rather the complexity of the alias I'm trying to set, but I just don't know what the error is trying to tell me.

The single quotes don't protect the double quotes that surround the format; the " immediately after format: closes the current string just as if the single quotes weren't there. You need to escape the " that are intended to be sent to the remote host as part of the shell command.
ssh me@my-vm "git config --global alias.l 'log --graph --all --pretty=format:\"%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset\"'" 

The resulting unquoted parts of the argument contain glob metacharacters, resulting in zsh attempting to match the argument against a file name in the current working directory and failing.
